# Is it possible to upload a "FlatFile Source" into "CosmosDB" using "SSIS"? (CoreSQL) always get this error

Tags: c#, azure, ssis, azure-cosmosdb

My Account of Cosmos DB is CORE (SQL), i've been trying what seems an easy test, upload a flat file source into a container in CosmosDB using SSIS.

My CosmosDB Container is called test, only has one item and the schema is the following

"id"= which is the required field to create an item
"_*"= non required fields created by CosmosDB

- I have a flat file with only one string and i set it as column "id".
- Downloaded the ODCB Driver and proceed to configure the connection using the Keys provided by Azure CosmosDB which they return an OK when testing them.
- Mapped the column from the flat file source into the column from the destination
  both as DT_WSTR and press run.

always return this error, if i try with numbers only changes the first number

- With only string

```
[ODBC Destination [15]] Error: Open Database Connectivity (ODBC) error occurred. SQLExecute returned error while inserting row 1
```

- With only numbers

```
[ODBC Destination [42]] Error: Open Database Connectivity (ODBC) error occurred. SQLExecute returned error while inserting row 1
```

Is it even possible to upload a flat file source into CosmosDB?

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well after struggling for a few days there's a way to upload a flat file into CosmosDB using SSIS.

When you create a container into CosmosDB you also add a partitionKey this partitionKey name **NEEDS** to be inside the flat file even if it doesnt appear in the schema or it seems to be required **IT IS REQUIRED**

So lets say your container looks like this  id, Zipcode (partitionKey)

your file should contain the ID and the Zipcode for it to map it into the CosmosDB

**ID AND PARTITION KEY ARE ALWAYS DT_WSTR**